# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute при вызове функции

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Столкнулся с вышеупомянутой ошибкой, вообще не пойму почему это так работает.
Начну с самого начала. Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы считывать значения комбобоксов и дальше использовать их как параметры для построения графика
У меня есть парочка csv файлов, с помощью комбобокса1 (есть еще 2: начальный год и конечный) я получаю имя файла, который мне нужно открыть следующим образом:

```
def initUX(self, provinceN):
value2 = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        value3 = self.comboBox_3.currentText()
        A = (int)(value2)
        B = (int)(value3)
        c = (A - 1981) * 52
        d = ((B - A)  * 52)
data = pd.read_csv("C://Users//vladi//PycharmProjects//pythonProject//venv//vhi_id_" +
                           provinceN + ".csv",skiprows=c,nrows=d, index_col=False, header=None)
        return data
```

Эту функцию я вызываю в другой, передав параметр provinceN, который и отвечает за имя файла.

Когда я пытаюсь построить график на основе этих данных, получаю ошибку 'DataFrame' object has no attribute
Если же я сделаю все аналогично, но вместо использования этой функции я просто создам этот объект и попробую - все получается, в чем же проблема?
Вот функция, которая строит график, которая делает все как надо:

```
    def createGraphh(self):
        value1 = self.comboBox.currentText()
        value2 = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        value3 = self.comboBox_3.currentText()
        A = (int)(value2)
        B = (int)(value3)
        c = (A - 1981) * 52
        d = ((B - A) * 52)

        data = pd.read_csv("C://Users//vladi//PycharmProjects//pythonProject//venv//vhi_id_crimea.csv", nrows=512)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
        plt.axis([0, 52*(B - A), 0, 100])
        plt.grid()

        plt.plot(df.index, df.G,'-r',linewidth=2)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.IndexLocator(104, 0))
        ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
        ax.set_xticklabels(df.A[::52])

  
        plt.axhspan(0, 15, facecolor='#A12020', alpha=0.5)
        plt.axhspan(15, 35, facecolor='#D78352', alpha=0.5)
        plt.axhspan(35, 60, facecolor='#B4D64E', alpha=0.5)
        plt.axhspan(60, 100, facecolor='#3DE11C', alpha=0.5)

        
        plt.show()
```

как мне вызывать первую функцию во второй правильно, чтобы все работало?
Имеется ввиду, что data

```
data = pd.read_csv("C://Users//vladi//PycharmProjects//pythonProject//venv//vhi_id_crimea.csv", nrows=512)
```

во второй функции это то же самое что и

```
data = self.initUX(value1)
```

Почему оно не работает?

ошибка:\

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vladi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\FAK.py", line 84, in createGraphh
    plt.plot(df.index, df.G,'-r',linewidth=2)
  File "C:\Users\vladi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5462, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'G'
```

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки полностью. И в какой строке она возникает. Может в вашем датафрейме просто нет столбца `G` или `A`. Проверьте, что там получается в датафрейме.

Comment: с датафреймом все в порядке, сейчас добавлю ошибку полностью в описание

Comment: Ну вот и нету у вас в датафрейме столбца `G` значит, судя по полному тексту ошибки. Может он у вас с пробелом там называется или с маленькой буквы или ещё чего. Сделайте `print(df.columns)` перед той строкой, в которой ошибка выходит - и всё выяснится.

Comment: проблема была в том, что я открывал файл, который не содержал эти самые столбцы, просто ошибка была изза моей невнимательности, спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Вы раньше писали на c++/c?

Comment: да, писал, а как это может быть связанно ?

Comment: никак, просто в python писать `(int)(value2)` необязательно можно просто `int(value2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема была в том, что я открывал файл, который не содержал эти самые столбцы, просто ошибка была изза моей невнимательности, спасибо за ответы!